# Naive query: VST plugins in ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg

I've recently discovered how powerful filtergraphs are in ffmpeg, and got hooked and have since been trying out more and more of the native filters of ffmpeg for audio processing, and then found out about the ladspa plugins.

This is all very neat.

But sadly, I couldn't find bass amp and bass cabinet emulations, and thought VST plugins had a lot to offer and would be a nice supplement to ffmpeg.

So here comes the naive question: couldn't VST plugins be supported by ffmpeg, like ladspa ? I know that the VST SDK has a linux command line VST Host you can compile for testing if a VST Plugin is compliant with their API format. Couldn't we discard all the test parts of this code and just keep the host part, and then just hook up the audio ins and outs to ffmpeg's signal chain ? I suppose also the parameters of the VST plugins are listed in some format ffmpeg could read and list out.

That'd be really nice wouldn't it ? Why wasn't it done yet ? Lack of interest ? License/Legal stuff ? Performance/compatibility issues my naive assumptions fail to forsee ?

Thanks for shedding some light on this !

PS: I am writing a command-line DAW in BASH that actually runs ffmpeg under the hood. It's nothing fancy, it just prompts the user with menus and commands to be able to interactively start/stop playback, change filter parameters, mute/solo audio, and do all of this dynamically using the zmqsend tool. It's not done yet but good progress is made and it allows to actually use ffmpeg as a terminal DAW. It's totally nerdy, but it does make it more useable. So having VST support would be great, I'd feel more at home with some plugins I know.

Comment: Open an enhancement request at trac.ffmpeg.org

Comment: @Arno, if you find out more at some later time, please answer your own question here with your finds.

Comment: Curious to know how your CLI DAW is progressing... ;)

Comment: Looking at the steinberg VST sdk license, i guess it's a legal issue but i may be wrong because they also state that the user can choose between their license and General Public License (GPL) Version 3:  [QUOTE] The SDK must not be used to re-engineer or manipulate any technology used
in any Steinberg or Third-party application or software module,
unless permitted by law.

Comment: Hello !
I wanted to update the status of this thread since I saw some comments. I have completed my Command Line DAW to a level where it got the very very, very very basic minimum things working. It was all written in BASH, it's actually a BASH script that uses all the default available utilities a lot of Linux distributions provide (I'm using Ubuntu). Example: tput for printing out things on the terminal like a canvas and moving the cursor around, etc.

Comment: My DAW had a file system that allowed the user to give name to LADSPA/LV2 parameters (because ffmpeg only gives generic names with numbers) that you could edit with my command line, and you could save your changes. That meant the user had to look up what the parameters do in the plugin description and give appropriate names to them. Work had to be done before starting to use the DAW, same as you would prepare a mixing template before starting a mixing session.

Comment: Then I opened an enhancement request at trac.ffmpeg.org as suggested, but sadly the person willing to help me and myself couldn't sync up properly because of whatever busy schedules with our lives and I don't think VST happened for ffmpeg. Moreover: I discovered Ardour, as I was looking around for LADSPA and LV2 plugins. It seems Ardour has LUA and OSC features that allow automating audio tasks like I was doing with ffmpeg (the reason I got so excited with ffmpeg in the first place was because I could script a lot of things)

Comment: And Ardour supports VST ! So now I'm actually interested in using Ardour and leave ffmpeg aside for a moment. My ffmpeg command line DAW was fun but improving it and maintaining it became a time vortex, and unless you have a very well planned ahead of time template for your mix project: any unforseen/unplanned change in the structure of the project implicates juggling a lot of files and/or menus to adapt so the workflow isn't as good as a real DAW, so the nerdy excitement of making audio in a command line wore off a bit and now I'm interested in Ardour.

Comment: So ! I don't know what to do with this thread, maybe we could close it ? The overall conclusion of it is that if you want VST and automation of audio, you should try going for Reaper (has OSC, is a very well established DAW that won't go away and has a lot of support) or Ardour (has OSC and LUA, a ton of extremely cool features regarding audio routing and configuration/customization, but is a bit more for Linux nerds/intermediate or advanced users).